# jQuery ajax success call not affecting the received elements

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to receive data from a .php file and displaying it on the page. The data received has a list of divs with the ids "question0" "question1" "question2" and so on. I need the success call to change certain css values for these elements. Here's my code,

```
$.ajax({ 
                            type: "POST",
                            data : { TestID: testID[0] },
                            cache: false,  
                            url: "load-test.php",   
                            success: function(data){
                                $(".main-section").html(data);
                                $("#question1").css('display','none');                      
                            }   
                        });   
                        return false; 
});
});
```

The list of divs is loaded onto the page, but the CSS is not affected, help!

Comment: Did you inspect your request in FireBug? Were there any js errors in the console?

Comment: Can you see the AjAX request being sent in FireBug? Is the `success` callback invoked?

Comment: The ajax part is working fine, it loads the content, but the part of the success callback which changes the CSS of the element isn't doing anything

Comment: do you have duplicate ID's in page?  ID's must be unique by definition and jQuery will only locate first one using an ID selector

Comment: Can we see the output from load-test.php?

Comment: You should create a fiddle with the sample code, there are plenty of reasons this could be happening but the code above doesn't provide enough information.  Also the `cache` option with a `POST` normally doesn't do anything.  And...why not just have the initial display settings in the initial CSS?

Comment: Maybe there are more than one `.main-section` on the page? If so, you will end up with duplicate IDs, like charlietfl mentioned.

Comment: If the HTML is being loaded, you must have hit "success."  Are you sure you have an element with ID "question1"?  Is it possible the ".main_section" inner HTML replacement is overwriting "#question1", so the CSS has nothing to hide?

Comment: simple check:  `alert( $([id="question1"]').length)` if zero, doesn't exist, if more than one you have duplicate ID's

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the #question1 ID was return from load-test.php, 
elements will not affect css after first run unless use class attribute instead,
but you also need to pre-define style for that class.